# Path Issue with Wordpress + Composer on Heroku

Tags: wordpress, heroku, composer-php

I am a newbie in composer and Heroku cloud and here has a may-be-stupid question about the path in composer.

I am trying to deploy a Wordpress on Heroku, following the code/instruction here: https://github.com/ellefsen/wordpress-heroku-php

In concept, I should use S3 to store any media content. However, my case is quite special: there are two and only two images for my site, now and in future. So I:

1. removed all S3 related code and configs;
2. add two images in public/content/uploads/ as: public/content/uploads/2016/08/one.png and public/content/uploads/2016/08/another.png;
3. adjust the .gitignore accordingly (remove the public/content/uploads);
4. Modify the composer.json as:

   ```html
         "extra": {
           "webroot-dir": "public/wp",
           "webroot-package": "wordpress",
           "installer-paths": {
             "public/content/plugins/{$name}/": [
               "type:wordpress-plugin"
             ],
             "public/content/mu-plugins/{$name}/": [
               "type:wordpress-muplugin"
             ],
             "public/content/uploads/{$name}/": [
               "public/wp/wp-content/uploads/{$name}"
             ],
             "public/content/themes/{$name}/": [
               "type:wordpress-theme"
             ]
           }
         },
   ```

For item "public/content/uploads/{$name}/", I tried:

- public/wp/wp-content/uploads/{$name}
- wp-content/uploads/{$name}

But in any case, within the WP dashboard, I cannot see any image in the media lib. Could someone please give me a hand? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not bother with the Media Library in WP as long as you are only dealing with two images. Just put them in your theme directory and reference them directly.

That way you won't have to deal with S3 or Heroku's ephemeral file storage as they would all be committed and included with your repository as part of your project.

Comment: Thanks Kim! Definitely your proposal will work, nearly perfect for my case. However, could you please also teach me why my solutions failed? I am eager to know the root reason. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem. For you to see your media in the Media Library you have to upload them via the wp-admin interface so they are stored in the database. Making them available from the uploads directory won't make them recognizable by WP.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation!